# Why does quote location matter in running devenv.com from the windows command line?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, command-line

I've been putting together a batch script (windows command line), and noticed some strange behavior with quoting paths containing spaces.

To reference locations with spaces (eg c:\Program Files), quotes must be used ("c:\Program Files"). For example, calling MSTest.exe, you would use:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
```

If you were going to also reference other programs in that location, you might do something like:

```
set VSDIR="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
%VSDIR%\MSTest.exe
```

The expanded call to MSTest.exe would look like this:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"\MSTest.exe
```

This works as expected. The quotes are stripped, and the system loads MSTest.exe. Great. Now, if I do the same thing for devenv.com:

```
set VSDIR="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
%VSDIR%\devenv.com
```

The system silently does nothing. No output is sent to standard out or error, and the error level remains at zero. Moving the quote after devenv.com loads the process as normal.

Anyone know why I'd see this behavior? Is it because devenv.com runs in real mode, or is it something about the process itself?

Comment: `.com`? WTF?!? I never, ever noticed that!

Comment: Yeah, .com is the extension for programs run in real (16-bit) mode.

Comment: I know. Just didn't ever expect that VS2010 would come with a .com file.

Comment: After looking at devenv.com in a hex editor, it looks like it isn't really a real mode program--it's actually compiled as a windows executable.

Comment: It is just a trick, the .com extension is selected before the .exe extension.  So if you only specify "devenv" then you get the command line version instead of the IDE.  The Windows loader isn't fooled by it, it looks at the file header and sees it is actually a relocatable executable.  Otherwise not a good explanation for quote behavior but maybe it is different for legacy 16-bit support reasons, no idea if that is real.